# syslog-ng support for multi-line to single line

Tags: syslog-ng

I have a syslog-ng running in a docker container, where I receive logs divided into several lines and my idea is to unite them into one and then be parsed with telegraf.
I couldn't make the correct configuration to transform the multi-lines to one line.
`- **Oct 25 13:00:00 10.249.27.20 CISE_Passed_Authentications 0027652254 3 0 2022-10-25 13:00:00.256** -03:00 2811881475 5203 NOTICE Device-Administration: Session Authorization succeeded, ConfigVersionId=761, Device IP Address=10.100.150.161,Step=22037, ...

- Oct 25 13:00:00 10.249.27.20 CISE_Passed_Authentications 0027652254 3 1  Step=15036, Step=15048, Step=15048, Step=15048, Step=15048, Step=15017, Step=22081, Step=22080, Step=13034, SelectedAuthenticationIdentityStores=Internal Users, AuthenticationStatus=AuthenticationPassed, ....
- Oct 25 13:00:00 10.249.27.20 CISE_Passed_Authentications 0027652254 3 2  Location=Location#All Locations, Device Type=Device Type#All Device Types, IPSEC=IPSEC#Is IPSEC Device,...
- **Oct 25 13:00:00 10.249.27.20 CISE_Passed_Authentications 0027652255 3 0 2022-10-25 13:00:00.261** -03:00 2811881488 5202 NOTICE Device-Administration: Command Authorization succeeded, ....`

## From already thank you very much

```
destination d_file {
   file(
        "/var/log/syslog_${HOST}_${YEAR}_${MONTH}_${DAY}_${HOUR}.log"
    owner("50000")
    group("root")
    perm(0777)
        );
};
```

```
source s_test_multiline {
  file("/var/log/tmp/logs.log" multi-line-mode(regexp) multi-line-prefix("[0-9]{10} \d{1} \d \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s*?") flags(no-parse));
};
```

```
destination d_test_multiline {
file("/var/log/tmp/logs_tacacs.log" 
  owner("50000")
  group("root")
  perm(0777)
  template("${MESSAGE}\n")
  flags(no-multi-line)
  #template("${LEGACY_MSGHDR} ${MESSAGE}\n")
);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A few months ago, someone had exactly this request, and although I can't remember all the details, this was the solution:

```
@version: 3.20
@include "scl.conf"

block parser cisco-ise-parser() {
    channel {
        parser {
            csv-parser(columns('1', '2', '3', 'MSG') flags(greedy));
            grouping-by(
                        scope("host")
                        key("$1")
                        sort-key('$3')
                        trigger("$(context-length)" eq "$2")
                        timeout(5)
                        aggregate(
                            inherit-mode(last-message)
                            #value("MESSAGE", '$(if "$(context-length) eq $2"  truncated)')
                            value("MESSAGE", "$(if ('$(context-length)' eq '$(+ $2 1)') 
                                                        '$1 1 0 $(implode \" \" $(list-slice :-1 $(context-values $MSG)))'
                                                        '$1 1 0 SYSLOG TRUNCATED $(list-slice :-1 $(context-values $3-$MSG))')")
                            tags(".cise.joined_message"))
            );
        };
        filter { tags(".cise.joined_message"); };
    };
};

log {
        source { tcp(port(2000)); };
        parser { cisco-ise-parser(); };
        destination { file("/install/foobar.log" template("$(format-welf --scope rfc3164 TAGS)\n")); };
};
```

The block above collects transactions into a single event. There could definitely be refinements here, but I hope this can help you getting started.